# Is it possible to add RubyMine to panel on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I've downloaded RubyMine archive and extracted it into my home directory. When I execute `./RubyMine/bin/rubymine.sh`, the IDE starts, and in Ubuntu panel, I can see RubyMine icon. When I right click on it, there is no such option as 'Add to favorites'. Is there any way to add RubyMine icon to the panel? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer from superuser worked for me:

https://superuser.com/questions/611065/how-to-add-rubymine-icon-to-the-left-top-panel-in-ubuntu

After starting RubyMine, go to:

```
    Tools->Create Desktop Entry
```

And go through the process.

That's it.